# Tags: live, live-sound, and live-performance

Tags: discussion

What is the intended difference between the `live` tag, the `live-sound` tag, and the `live-performance` tag? The `live-sound` tag is the only one with usage guidance and I assume anything that is `live-performance` but not `live-sound` belongs on music.stackexchange.com. Is that a poor assumption?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the fact that the `live-preformance` tag should be removed, as it's not applicable to sound design, as for `live`, this could mean anything from a DJ set to an orchestra concert. and `live-preformance` would be for setting up a stage for a concert (determining the best position for each different instruments, like violins on the far left and right side of the stage with contrabass and/or cello's behind them, drums behind those and also in the center back, etc)

that's what I assume those tags to be atleast...